# Connecting django with ajax

Tags: django

I was able to hook ajax with django, but I'm running into the following problem.
In my ajax function, I have this:

```
function submitForm() {
var contactForm = $(this);

if ( !$('#senderName').val() || !$('#senderEmail').val() || !$('#message').val() ) {

$('#incompleteMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
contactForm.fadeOut().delay(messageDelay).fadeIn();

} else {

$('#sendingMessage').fadeIn();
contactForm.fadeOut();

$.ajax( {
url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
data: contactForm.serialize(),
success: submitFinished
} );
}

return false;
}
```

And the view now looks like this:

```
def postMessageForm(request):
if request.POST:
print "POST"

if request.GET:
print "GET"
```

How do I tell the view to send the success variable back so the code continues?
In php, it would be something like this:
    ....
    if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
    echo $success ? "success" : "error";

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm is it

```
if 'ajax' in request.GET:
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'success':'success','other_stuff':}))

else:
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'success':'error','other_stuff':}))
```

But u can check whether request is ajax by using `request.is_ajax()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there any other way to solve this without using simplejson?

Comment: you can just replace in plain text "success" or "error" instead of that. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse